# wrong header in bibliography & list of figures / tables

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer, koma-script

I am finalizing a thesis and encountered an issue regarding the page header. During the thesis, the header is defined as the name of the current sections. As far as I understand the provided class, this is obtained by

```
\RequirePackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{section}
```

which is the way it is supposed to work. However, the first issue appears when there is a chapter without any section, i.e. chapter 6 is the conclusion without a 6.1. Then, 5.4, which was the previous section, is displayed throughout chapter 6. I fixed this by adding

```
\automark{chapter}
```

at the beginning of the conclusion. This works as intended, although there might be a more sophisticated and general solution to this problem.

However #2, after the conclusions, there is the bibliography, the list of figures and the list of tables. Only the bibliography has the header of either chapter 6 or section 5.4 (depending on whether i include the automark{chapter} command or not), the other lists show as intended in the header. So, there should be "bibliography" in the header of the bibliography. Unfortunately, I don't know how. The lists are generated by the commands

```
\printbibliography % Print literature
\listoffigures % Show list of figures
\listoftables % Show list of tables
```

without any further information on them, even in the class file.

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks in advance!
Please let me know if any required information is missing.

Comment: Is your document onesided or twosided? Only a guess: Use `\automark{chapter}\automark*{section}` in the preamble. For your second problem add a minimal working example showing the issue.

Comment: Currently, it's one-sided but I will probably generate a two-sided version as well. I was able to resolve the issue by defining \automark{chapter} once again after the mainpart ended, i.e. right before the bibliography (and then adding another \automark{section} before the appendix). This leads to the desired result, but appears not to be the most favorable solution...

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion for a onesided document:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{chapter}
\automark*{section}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\chapter{Foo}
\Blindtext[20]
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

And one possibility for a twosided document:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\automark*[section]{section}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\chapter{Foo}
\Blindtext[20]
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```